# wait() in a while (true) loop to simulate a Clock in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, notify

Im trying to simulate a digital clock in Java by using wait() and notify(). If i run the following Code (well, actually a other very simlue GUI Class to display the Clock) i get a Illegal Monitor Exception. Im new to Java, so probably Ive used wait() the wrong way....

```
public class JDigitalClock extends JLabel implements Runnable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private boolean stopped = false;
DateTimeFormatter dtf;
LocalDateTime now;

public JDigitalClock() {
    dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");
    now = LocalDateTime.now();
    setText(dtf.format(now));
    setFont(new Font("Sans Serif", Font.PLAIN, 70));
    setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        sleep();
        while (getStopped())
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        now = LocalDateTime.now();
        setText(dtf.format(now));
    }

}

public void setStopped(boolean stopped) {
    this.stopped = stopped;
    if (!stopped)
        notify();
}

public boolean getStopped() {
    return this.stopped;
}

public void sleep() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html

Comment: The [Javadoc for `wait()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait()) explains why it throws that exception, only, when you read it, you have to know that "not the owner of the object's monitor" means "inside a `synchronized` block." You may only put a `foo.wait()` call inside a `synchronized(foo){...}` block.